# How to get "virtualhost" functionality in Go?

Tags: go, virtualhost

With Nginx/Django create virtualhosts is as easy as to write appropriate config.

For Go I found this https://codereview.appspot.com/4070043 and I understand that I have to use `ServeMux` but how to implement it?

I mean I must have 1 binary for all projects or I have to create some "router" server which will route requests depending on hostname? How to do it "Go"-way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are correct that you will use the ServeMux.  The [godoc for ServeMux](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) has some detailed information about how to use it.

In the standard http package, there is the DefaultServeMux which can be manipulated using the top-level Handle functions.  For example, a simple virtual host application might look like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, world!")
    })
    http.HandleFunc("qa.example.com/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, improved world!")
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

In this example, all requests to qa.example.com will hit the second handler, and all requests to other hosts will hit the first handler.

Comment: I'm curious about the second part of his question pertaining to the number of binaries required. Do you need to compile all of your separate virtual host projects into one binary for ServeMux to multiplex correctly? The only other method I can think of is using the os package to execute other go binaries, which seems just wrong.

Comment: related to this: How to run two web servers in the same go program:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183183/running-two-web-server-at-the-same-time-in-one-go-programm

Comment: @MorganFreeman To use the method I outlined here, you will execute a single Go binary that is serving on a single host.  All virtualized hostnames must resolve to that host that's running your binary.

Comment: Requests to qa.example.com/ don't work for me. Is there something else I should to? I added this in hosts file:
127.0.0.1       http://qa.example.com/
but still doesn't work

Comment: @zuzuleinen Check r.Host in the request you're getting, and make sure that it says "qa.example.com" -- if it doesn't, something else is wrong (e.g. the client is using HTTP 1.0).  You could also try gorilla mux's Host() matcher.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example of how to provide the "virtual hosts" functionality using golang:

```
package main

import(
    "net/url"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
)

func main() {
    vhost1, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:1980")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    proxy1 := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(vhost1)
    http.HandleFunc("publicdomain1.com/", handler(proxy1))

    vhost2, err := url.Parse("http://127.0.0.1:1981")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
    proxy2 := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(vhost2)
    http.HandleFunc("publicdomain2.com/", handler(proxy2))

    err = http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
          panic(err)
    }
}

func handler(p *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            p.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

In this case each "virtual host" can be any http server, like other golang net.http web server or even other conventional web server like nginx. Each of them can be either in the same ip and in another port, or in another ip and any port. It doesn't matter if you are forwarding to a different physical server if you wish to do it.